# This action is not allowed to set a user message because this property was not requested for approval

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know what this means "This action is not allowed to set a user message because this property was not requested for approval".

I'm trying to post an acion to the Facebook Graph and they are returning that message.

My app actions have been approved.  The user token is valid.

Not sure what is going on...

Comment: I should also mentioned that my perms are set to publish_stream and publish_actions...

Comment: Got it... I was sending a form param named message via cfhttp post.  Facebook didn't like that.  I took it out and its publishing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have an unapproved action and you are not using the facebook account used for creating the action